# How to relate UIKit, Core Image, Quartz 2D, and the various frameworks in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, quartz-graphics

It is clear to me so far that UIKit is on top of Core Graphics and Core Animation, and what Core Graphics and Core Animation can do, UIKit has some higher level method to do them as well.

How about the other layers, Core Image, Quartz 2D, Quartz, Quartz Core, Quartz Graphics, Core Video, Cocoa Touch, Core Motion.  How do they relate to each other?  (is there a good diagram that depicts where they belong in the iOS precisely?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quartz = Quartz 2D = Core Graphics. From a programmer's perspective, these are just different names for the same thing. Apples calls its graphics engine Quartz (2D), which is part of the Core Graphics framework. If you want to use Quartz (2D) in your code, you use the APIs defined in the Core Graphics framework.

Quartz Graphics: I've never heard this one before but it's probably just another name for Quartz/Core Graphics.

Core Image is another framework (appeared first on the Mac and recently on iOS) whose primary focus is image manipulation. Core Image allows you to apply a set of pre-defined or custom graphics filters on an image. Core Image is known to be very fast as it uses the GPU very effectively to apply these filters. Recently, Core Image got another feature: face detection in images.

(I don't know too much about Core Video so I'd be grateful if others could add more about that topic.)

Comment: It seems that Core Graphics == Quartz 2D, and Core Animation is part of Quartz Core.  But since Quartz Core == Core Animation + Core Image + Core Video on Mac OS X, but on iOS, Core Image and Core Video are not part of Quartz Core, so Core Animation == Quartz Core on iOS

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Begemann's answer.  I found more info on http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/WhatIsCocoa/WhatIsCocoa.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH3-SW16

Although it may not be complete, here is an overview:

---

**On Mac OS X:**

[image]

---

**On iOS:**

[image]

**excerpt:**

> The following summarizes some of the frameworks found at each layer of
> the iOS stack, starting from the foundation layer.
>
> **Core OS**. This level contains the kernel, the file system, networking
> infrastructure, security, power management, and a number of device
> drivers. It also has the libSystem library, which supports the
> POSIX/BSD 4.4/C99 API specifications and includes system-level APIs
> for many services.
>
> **Core Services**. The frameworks in this layer provide
> core services, such as string manipulation, collection management,
> networking, URL utilities, contact management, and preferences. They
> also provide services based on hardware features of a device, such as
> the GPS, compass, accelerometer, and gyroscope. Examples of frameworks
> in this layer are Core Location, Core Motion, and System
> Configuration.
>
> This layer includes both Foundation and Core
> Foundation, frameworks that provide abstractions for common data types
> such as strings and collections. The Core Frameworks layer also
> contains Core Data, a framework for object graph management and object
> persistence.
>
> **Media**. The frameworks and services in this layer depend on the Core
> Services layer and provide graphical and multimedia services to the
> Cocoa Touch layer. They include Core Graphics, Core Text, OpenGL ES,
> Core Animation, AVFoundation, Core Audio, and video playback.
>
> **Cocoa Touch**. The frameworks in this layer directly support applications
> based in iOS. They include frameworks such as Game Kit, Map Kit, and
> iAd.
>
> The Cocoa Touch layer and the Core Services layer each has an
> Objective-C framework that is especially important for developing
> applications for iOS. These are the core Cocoa frameworks in iOS:
>
> **UIKit**. This framework provides the objects an application displays in
> its user interface and defines the structure for application behavior,
> including event handling and drawing. For a description of UIKit, see
> “UIKit (iOS).”
>
> **Foundation**. This framework defines the basic behavior
> of objects, establishes mechanisms for their management, and provides
> objects for primitive data types, collections, and operating-system
> services. Foundation is essentially an object-oriented version of the
> Core Foundation framework; see “Foundation” for a discussion of the
> Foundation framework.